# Do two classes of the same class have the same hashcode and are they considered equal?

Tags: java

I want to create a hashmap of classes like (Object.class). I am wondering whether

Object.class is considered equal to another Object.class?

Can there be another instance of Object.class which leads it to have different hashcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal `Object.class` will always return the same reference within the same classloader.

From [section 15.8.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2):

> A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader of the class of the current instance.

Note the definite article ("the") in the quote above - there's only *one* `Class` object for any particular class, within the same class loader.

So yes, you'll get the same hashcode - because you'll have two references to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Within a given class loader, for each loaded class there's a single object of type `Class`.

`x1.getClass()` and `x2.getClass()` return the same reference as long as `x1` and `x2` have the same dynamic type.

Answer (score 2):

Since we have only one instance of a .class object for each typed class, all references will be pointing to this same object (of Object.class) and hence will have the same hashcode (as the underlying object is same)